# Can not charge using Paypal SDK in live mode in iOS

Tags: ios, transactions, paypal

I have integrated PayPal SDK to my iOS app. Transactions work fine in Sandbox mode, but when switching to Live mode in PayPal and charge with Paypal account or credit card, the Paypal api always fail with error

```
"status": 403,
 "duration_time": 239,
 "body": {
  "message": "No permission for the requested operation",
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "name": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "debug_id": "e2ccd1a53d228"
 },
 "additional_properties": {},
 "header": {
  "Content-Length": "187",
  "Content-Language": "*",
  "CORRELATION-ID": "e2ccd1a53d228",
  "Date": "Fri, 05 Feb 2016 06:33:31 GMT",
  "Paypal-Debug-Id": "e2ccd1a53d228",
  "PROXY_SERVER_INFO": "host\\u003dslcjavapapi3035b;threadId\\u003d269",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
 }
}
```

One more time, it works in Sandbox mode
and I also switched all ClientID and Live mode on app and on PayPal App console.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you followed as said in this procedure:- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

Comment: Thank @Vizllx, I go through it but still fail